# Vuejs 2 http.post returning with Media Type unsupoorted

Tags: java, vue.js, jersey

I have tried several times and I am getting MediaType unsupported from the vuejs response. I am new to Vuejs 2 and I am currently trying to post form data to Java Jersey Restful Service that consumes and produces Media type: APPLICATION_JSON.

This is my data from vue;

```
var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('email', this.email);
 formData.append('password', this.password);
 this.$http.post('myurl', formData).then(response => {response.status;
            }, response => {
                console.log('Error: ' + response.status);
            });
```

A working sample would do me a lot of good.

Comment: You'd better also provide Java code otherwise it will be really difficult to analyse.

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).